# Show list of days of week except Sunday

Tags: php

I'm attempting to show a list of the days of week excluding Sunday. The first day on the list should be whatever-day-it-is-today with a CSS class of 'active'. If today = Sunday, the first list item should be Monday.

Below is the code I'm using. The problem is, this outputs the first 6 days from today (including Sunday) and then misses out the-7th-day-from-today.

Any idea what I need to change to get it to skip Sunday instead?

```
function daysofweek() {

$datetime = new \DateTime();

$listItem = array('<li class="active"><a href="#', '" data-toggle="tab">', '</a></li>');

$i = 0;

echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';

    while (true) {
        if ($i === 6) break;

        if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
            $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
            continue;        
        }

        $the_day = $datetime->format('D');

        echo $listItem[0] . $the_day . $listItem[1] . $the_day . $listItem[2];
        $listItem = array('<li><a href="#', '" data-toggle="tab">', '</a></li>');    

        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        $i++;
    }

echo '</ul>';
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad way to code

```
while(true)
```

This ALWAYS evaluates to true. Even with your `break` this is poor syntax. Your `while` should contain the logic. So here's your code, restructured. I removed the duplicate call to `add()` and made it run for every iteration. The loop naturally terminates itself as well.

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 7) {
    $the_day = $datetime->format('N');
    if($the_day != 7) {
         echo $listItem[0] . $the_day . $listItem[1] . $the_day . $listItem[2];
         $listItem = array('<li><a href="#', '" data-toggle="tab">', '</a></li>');      
    }
    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a function that returns an array, instead of writing the output inside it. Here my explanation first:

- To get the current date, use the `time` function.
- To get the numeric representaion of current day of the week, use `date` function with value `'w'` as first argument. It will return `0` for Sunday through `6` for Saturday.
- To get the next date, add the current date with `(24 * 60 * 60)`. That would be 86,400 seconds or 1 days from current time. The value `24` is for the hour, the first `60` is the minute, and the last `60` is the second.
- To get the name of current day of the week, use `date` function with value `'l'` (lowercase of letter `L`) as first argument.

Nuff said, here's the function:

```
function weekDaysFromToday() {
  $days = array();
  $date = time();
  while (count($days) < 7) {
    $date += (24 * 60 * 60);
    if (!date('w', $date)) continue;
    $days[] = date('l', $date);
  }
  return $days;
}
```

If you want that the current day is not repeated at the end of the list, you should change the `while (count($days) < 7)` into `while (count($days) < 6)`.

And here's the code to render the array using your code above:

```
$days = weekDaysFromToday();
$active = ' class="active"';
echo "<ul class=\"nav nav-tabs\">\n";
foreach ($days as $day) {
  echo "<li$active><a href=\"#$day\" data-toggle=\"tab\">$day</a></li>\n";
  $active = '';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

There you are, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same thing in much more concise formatting:

```
$today = date('w');
$first = 1;
for($i=$today; $i<$today+7; $i++){
    if($i%7) echo "<li ".($first ? "class='active'" : '').">".date('D', strtotime("Sunday +".($i%7)." days"))."<li>";
    $first=0;
}
```

It works by using the modulo `%7` to cycle through the week, starting from today.